# is there a argparse module that auto detects the data type

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Is there any other python package or does argparse has the following feature I am expecting

```py
arg_parser.add_argument("-v", "--some_data", required=True,
                        help="data id(int) or vehicle name (str) ")
```

```
input -v 123 output type(args.some_data) --> int
input -v abc output type(args.some_data) --> str
input -v a12 output type(args.some_data) --> str
```

Comment: By default all arguments are treated as `str`, but you can use `str.isnumeric` or `str.isdecimal`.

Comment: this behaviour (automatic "I know what you meant" typing) is often seen as an anti-feature -- but you could use something like `type=yaml.safe_load` -- or your own function which does `try: except:` with `int(...)`

Comment: What is the type of "0xff" - integer or string? You should define the rules explicitly, and refuse the temptation to guess. There is no such "guess" feature in argparse.

Comment: There are many commandline parsers in the Pypi repository, some built on `argparse`, others parsing from ground up.  So it's hard to say whether any or none have this feature.  `argparse` doesn't do this, but you could write your own `type` function that does what you want.  That function just has to accept a string, and return some value (or raise an error).  The rest is up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) that tries to parse an int, and if it fails, returns the string.

(I made your option an argument in this example for simplicity.)

```
import argparse

def int_or_str(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("x", type=int_or_str, help="int or str")
print(parser.parse_args(['123']))  # -> Namespace(x=123)
print(parser.parse_args(['hello']))  # -> Namespace(x='hello')
```

However, beware that `int` ignores leading and trailing whitespace, so for example `int(' 1 ')` succeeds.

```
print(parser.parse_args([' 1 ']))  # -> Namespace(x=1)
```